# Undo or Remove slideUp

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following bit of code:

```
        $("#content-listing").slideUp(800, function(){
            $("#loading").hide();
        });
```

Which works fine. But is there a method to "undo" slideUp or remove its functionality?

I am using `matchMedia`to apply certain functions depending on a user's screen size. If a browser window is resized, `slideUp`interferes with the newly transformed layout and so I am trying to find a way to remove it?

Comment: [.slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) undo [.slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/). You can try to use other effect, like [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was applying a class to the `body` tag `onclick` so that I can specifically refer to the mobile div to cast the jQuery voodoo on:

```
$("body").addClass("mobile");
```

To which:

```
    $("body.mobile #content-listing").slideUp(function(){
        $("#loading").hide();
    });
```

And then once the `window.resize`happens, I remove the `mobile` class from the `body`:

```
$("body").removeClass("mobile");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for $("#...").stop();

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 0):

I'd be putting a conditional statement around the slideUp code.

Something like

```
var isMobile = //whatever you're using to decide what your toggle threshold is

if(isMobile)
{

    $("#content-listing").show();
    //Or whatever you want to do in the case of a small screen
} else {
    $("#content-listing").slideUp(800, function(){
        $("#loading").hide();
    });
}
```

Comment: The problem comes when the browser is resized or the orientation is changed. Once `slideUp`has been added to the dom, it stays there. That's what I am trying to remove specifically.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(window).width() <= 400 ) {
     $("#content-listing").slideUp(800, function(){
     $("#loading").hide();
}
```

you can also try `resize` event:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var w = $(this).width();

  if (w <= '400') {
      $("#content-listing").slideUp(800, function(){
          $("#loading").hide();
      });
  }       
})
```

*update:*

try [`dequeue()`](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) method:

```
      $("#content-listing").queue('slide', function(){
           $(this).slideUp(800, function(){
                $("#loading").hide();
           });
      })

      if (w <= '400') {
          $("#content-listing").dequeue('slide')
      }
```

Comment: The problem is once `slideUp`is added to the dom, it stays there. So even if I resize the window back up to, say, 800px, the slideUp functionality will still be attached.

Comment: @Yahreen try `dequeue()` method.

Comment: Hmmm...Console is not reporting any errors...My ajax loader gif just spins, the `slideUp`never occurs. here's what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/yjMEK/